# Split a plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How to split my graph into two graphs? I have been using this code

```
ggplot(maris,aes(x=reorder(Municipio,Municipio,function(x)-length(x)))) +
       ggtitle("Municipios") + geom_bar(fill="red",colour="black") +
       theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12,angle = -90, hjust = 1),
             axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold",))
```

`maris` is my dataset and `Municipio` is what I want to plot but there are more than 300 results and you can't see it clearly in the graph.

Any ideas?

Comment: So make your plot really wide.

Answer (score 0):

You could facet the data by some value. Here I have used `facet_wrap` to split some data alphabetically

```
ggplot(data.frame(month.name, y = rnorm(12), b = substr(month.name,1,1)<"m"), aes(month.name, y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~b, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x")
```

You would probably want to change the theme to remove the facet labels.